# How to transform '"Who's next please?" She wanted to know' into indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

[image]

I added a *that*, changed and switched the verb.
So my answer was *She wanted to know who the next was.* But the correct one is *She wanted to know who was next.* Why the verb stayed at the exactly same spot as before. Was *that* incorrect to use here? Can anyone gives me clarifications on this?

Comment: _She wanted to know who was [the] next [person in the queue/line]._  You could say _who the next person was_, but you can't use _was_ following an adjective on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky case! I see two questions here, one about the word **next** changing roles and the other about using **who** and **that** in a relative clause.

**tl;dr**: you are close with the word order, but the word **next** is doing different jobs in each of the sentences. And you can think of **who** as standing in for **that + subject** where the subject isn't known to the person/thing in the earlier part of the sentence. If she knew who was next, but just wanted to confirm it, the sentence could be

> She wanted to confirm **that he** was next.

---

More information if you're interested:

The word **next** isn't really a noun, even though it looks like it's acting as the object of the question. It's actually an ellipsis of a noun phrase like "the next person in line"

> Who's **next** please? She wanted to know.
>
> Who is **the next person in line** please? She wanted to know

If you use the shortened version, the word order in the restatement ends up being different because **next** as a regular adjective can only go in one place:

> She wanted to know who **was next.**

If you use the full noun phrase, it can go either way:

> She wanted to know who **the next person in line was.**
>
> She wanted to know who **was the next person in line.**

---

On the second point, **who** in English can operate as two different kinds of word: an interrogative pronoun ("Who...?") and a relative pronoun ("...who..."). The [Who (pronoun) wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_(pronoun)) has some good examples. **That** can also be a relative pronoun in specific, non-restrictive instances like this one, if the subject is not an unknown person and is specified in the relative clause.

So even though both words have more than one use in English, in this scenario, **that** and **who** would play a similar role grammatically (not semantically), as the relative pronoun, and so using both in the same sentence is ungrammatical and unidiomatic.

But even when the subject is known, **who** is used as the subject of the relative clause when referring to people, as in

> The man **who** accepted the gift.

Unlike in the OP's sentence though, **that** can be substituted here without arousing too much suspicion in an informal context

> The man **that** accepted the gift

even though a grammar snob might get on your case because "the man" is a human, not an inanimate subject.

If all that isn't confusing, you must not be thinking about it very much (native speaker bias)! See the [English relative clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses) article for way too many rules and exceptions.